# Delete only directory contents using chef

Tags: windows, chef-infra

Is there a way I can delete only the contents of a directory without deleting the actual parent directory? When I use recursive and action delete, the actual parent directory is also getting deleted.

If I specify a path C:\chef\mydir, then all the contents of this dir (files and sub directories) must get deleted, basically emptying. I am in a Windows environment.

Any guidance in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a great way to do this in Chef (or even just in raw Ruby). You can crib from my code though: https://github.com/poise/poise-archive/blob/master/lib/poise_archive/archive_providers/base.rb#L115-L119

Just put that in a `ruby_block` and you should be okay.

Comment: Thank you. This approach worked to "empty" the directory.

Comment: Please include a small sample of the code here.  Links often break.  Link-only answers are to be avoided.

Comment: @TrippKinetics If Github goes down, we probably have larger problems than questions about a legacy ops tool from forever ago.

Comment: @coderanger Perhaps, but I disagree in principle.  Stack Overflow needs to stand on its own.

Answer (score 1):

In linux you can run something like `rm -r dir/**/*` to delete all the files in the directory. This won't delete the parent directory. You can add this to chef recipe.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about windows but you can try:

> Actions This resource has the following actions:
>
> :nothing 
>   Prevent a command from running. This action is used to
>   specify that a command is run only when another resource notifies it.
>
> :run Default. 
>   Run a command.

```
execute "delete_files" do
  command "del /s /q /F *"
  cwd "C:\chef\mydir"
end
```

Delete single file:

```
file 'delete_files' do
  path 'C:\\chef\\mydir\\my.file'
  action :delete
end
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Most of these are not a good idea. windows_path has nothing to do with directories (it's about the $PATH env var), and the globs (`*`s) in file resource paths won't work.

Comment: thanks for your comment, never used chef with windows :)

Answer (score 1):

With my limited knowledge of Chef, I did the following as I knew how to delete an entire directory and how to create new directories. The approach taken was to delete the directory and then recreate the same directory, instead of trying to "empty" it. This may be crude, but it served my purpose.

```
directory my_temp_dir do
recursive true
action [:delete, :create]
only_if {::Dir.exist?(my_temp_dir)}
end
```

The create action will execute only after the delete action and the condition "directory must exist" has to be satisfied. This way, we can ensure directories are not unnecessarily created on servers as the ultimate objective is to "empty" the directory.

Comment: This is a great answer. I'd say you don't need the only_if though. Chef does this logic itself. if the directory, doesn't exist, it know's :delete doesn't need to converge and creates it. If it does exist, then it will delete it and then run :create since it doesn't exist anymore